# Problem with DataMapper, Integer property

Tags: datamapper

I have the following class in my sinatra app (app.rb)

```
class Project
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :creatorid, Integer, :key => false
  property :name, String
end


Project.auto_migrate! unless Project.storage_exists?
```

and in the `post` method, I have:

```
project = Project.create
project.creatorid = GetLoggedInUserId() #returns an int
project.name = params['projectname']
```

But when I'm getting the following error:
`no such column: creatorid` (on the `project.creatorid`... line)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coult try with `new` method instead that `create` since latter one is used to generate and save an item on the go while the former one is used to generate an empty item that can be then filled (like you do) and then saved with `project.save()`.

Take a look at documentation [here](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy)..

Comment: Ok, I did that, got a new/different error: table projects has no column named creatorid

Comment: Maybe you should check that migration works before trying to insert elements, did you check the DB?

Comment: that was it, the migration failed. I deleted the db and started again. any ideas on how I could investigate why the migration failed?